# Inexact first order differential equations

Tags: calculus

I have been solving an inexact first order ODE, but arriving to the step of finding an integrating factor /mu, I was enable to find either /mu of x or /mu of y. Is there another way of solving this ODE? or how can I come up with the solution.

$$(e^{x+y}-ye^{x})\mathrm dx+e^{y}\mathrm dy=0$$

Thank you for you kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(e^{x+y}-ye^{x})dx+e^{y}dy=0$ thus $e^x(e^y-y)dx=-e^{y}dy$ so $$e^xdx=\frac{-e^{y}}{e^y-y }dy$$

Comment: I.e., @Esdras, this ODE is separable.